# Google Finance returns currency for US stocks but not others (for example UK)

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

Google Finance, in Google Sheets, works for US stocks but not others (for example UK).

US stock:
`msft`

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("msft","price")`  **works**

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("msft","currency")`  **works**

UK stock:
`lon:barc`

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("lon:barc","price")`  **works**

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("lon:barc","currency")`  **does not work**

Calling a non US stock, in this example, one from the London Stock Exchange, returns a #N/A error. With the error message "*Function GOOGLEFINANCE parameter 2 value is invalid for the symbol specified*".

According to the documentation

1. parameter 1, is `ticker`
2. parameter 2, is `currency`

The stock currency was working previously, but stopped working a while (over 6 months) ago and has never been fixed as far as I can tell.

Is there a fix for this problem?

Comment: Google Finance doesn't support all stocks. For details see https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have visited this page before, but do not see what is or is not supported on this page. Is there a page that clearly shows what is supported or a method to find this out (other than by inspection of each item) ?

Comment: Have you also viewed this link: [Quotes are not sourced from all markets and may be delayed up to 20 minutes](https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/#realtime) (it's included in the previous referred page)?

Comment: hi Ruben:  No, I have not. But looking at this link, it **does not** relate to the quoted currency of the ticker (ie. GBP, USD. EUR etc...). It only refers to real-time pricing and the delays (minutes) which is not relevant to the solution.